# How to use data passed from a list passed to another class, and pass that to another class?

Tags: android, android-intent

OK, I see a LOT of questions on Stack overflow with regards to passing data from a list view to another class upon clicking on it via intents, but my question is different. So I have list items which when I click on opens a notes class, in  there is the list title and the body, the title is the same as the list item clicked. Inside this class I have a button which opens another class, I need the title to be passed here too, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is in the SQL Lite DB, how it passed and how to pass it via a button.

Here is the onclick listener for the list item:

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT); 
}
```

Here is the class that takes this and displays the title, body and button which I need to also pass on the title data, I have commented above the button:

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private Long mRowId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });

    //HERE IS THE BUTTON WHICH I USE TO GET TO THE NEXT ACTIVITY, I NEED TO PASS THE DATA IN TITLE FROM HERE!!

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openNext = new Intent("com.timer.RUNNING");
                startActivity(openNext);
            }
            });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));

    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body);
    }
  }
 }
```

I hope this question made sense, I got stuck when I had to go from an onclick from a list to still passing that information using a button. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use static variables. set value in that variables from your class to another class where you want to go. may this help you

Comment: I chose your answer as that is how I got it to work, by creating a static variable which I returned in a method called from the other class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Send title data to next Activity as:

```
   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
           //Intent openNext = new Intent("com.timer.RUNNING");
           Intent openNext = new Intent(Current_Activity.this,NextActivity.this);
           openNext.putExtra("title",mTitleText.getText().toString());
           startActivity(openNext);
          }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried this but couldn't get it to work but I think I see how you meant to do it, cheers!!

Comment: @deucalion0 :  any valid reason why my solution is not working because it's right way for sending data to other components and use of static variables in android application is bad practice . any way your choice

Comment: Sorry, I tried your idea, it just would not work, I think I needed some code in the next activity to receive the put extra? I researched and tried things but it wouldn't work, which is unfortunate as this would have been better than using static variables. I appreciate your help though.